# GCC Assembly "+t"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm currently testing some inline assembly in C++ on an old compiler (GCC circa 2004) and I wanted to perform the square root function on a floating point number. After trying and searching for a successful method, I came across the following code

```
float r3(float n){
    __asm__("fsqrt" : "+t" (n));
    return n;
};
```

which worked. The issue is, even though I understand the assembly instructions used, I'm unable to find any particular documentation as to what the `"+t"` flag means on the `n` variable. I'm under the genuine idea that it seems to be a manner by which to treat the variable `n` as both the input and output variable but I was unable to find any information on it. So, what exactly is the `"t"` flag and how does it work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+`

> Means that this operand is both read and written by the instruction.
>   (From [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html))

`t`

> Top of 80387 floating-point stack (%st(0)).
>   (From [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html))

Answer (score 3):

`+` means you are reading and writing the register.
`t` means the value is on the top of the 80387 floating point stack.

References:

- GCC manual, [Extended Asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) has general information about constraints - search for "constraints"
- GCC manual, [Machine Constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) has information about the specific constraints supported on each architecture - search for "x86 family"